# How are the number of representatives for each of eight legally recognised minor political parties in the People's Republic of China determined?

Tags: china

How are the number of representatives for each of eight legally recognised minor political parties in the People's Republic of China determined? Surprisingly, there are eight legally recognised minor political parties in the People's Republic of China Standing Committee of the National People's Congress of the People's Republic of China. There are currently 9 representatives from the China Democratic League, 7 from the China Association for Promoting Democracy, 7 from the Chinese Peasants' and Workers' Democratic Party and so on. How are these determined by the government of the People's Republic of China?

Comment: Did the source mention how many people are exposed to or working with each minority party? The seats could be in proportion to its membership compared to the controlling party.